# Asp.Net version hosting confusion

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem with understanding which version I am using. I have created my application based on this course: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/aspdotnet-5-ef7-bootstrap-angular-web-app/ but after quick checking in the internet I got completely confused. Am I using asp.net core, asp.net 5, asp.net vnext? Currently I believe my project is done in MVC 6, but asp.net version confuses me. I am also looking for a hosting provider that supports MVC 6 (and the asp.net version that I am using). I found some that supposedly support these version, but not being sure about my version holds me back from spending money on them.

Comment: ASP.NET VNext was the "code name" for ASP.NET 5 prior to its pseudo-release.  ASP.NET 5 was the end result of ASP.NET VNext, and this has been subsequently renamed to ASP.NET Core 1.0.  And it's still not RTM.

Comment: So this means that having my project done I can't host it?

Comment: I suppose title of the course should give a hint `Building a Web App with ASP.NET Core RC1`

Comment: That's a question for your hosting company, not SO.

Comment: That's one of the problems, as I don't have hosting company because I don't want to pay if I won't be able to host my website.

Comment: I think the question you need to ask is not whether or not a hosting company can host your MVC 6 app, but whether you want to be developing an application for (I'm assuming) production use on a framework that isn't even RTM yet.

Comment: It's not really for production. More for portfolio. While doing the course I didn't know it's not RTM. I just want to be able to show it as a part of my portfolio.

Comment: Then look for a hosting company that supports ASP.NET Core 1.

Comment: ASP.NET Core runs as an application, so any hoster that allows you to run an executable file (virtual private server, managed server) etc. will allow you to run ASP.NET Core. If build against full .NET Framework you also need to make sure you can install mono framework on that webspace as it's required when run under linux. Same for windows hosting, as you need 4.5.1 or higher and not all hosts may come with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That course has been renamed to ASP.NET Core RC1 to clear up that confusion. It will be updated to RC2 and RTM when those happen too. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for claryfying that for me. As for the second part of the problem. Is it possible to host the website somewhere or I have to wait for future updates of ASP.Net?

Comment: Hosting in Azure Websites currently work well, but I don't know if any hosts support it yet. You might try discountasp.com if Azure doesn't work for you.